# Android Studio Virtualization Stopped Working

Tags: android-studio, virtualization, bios, amd-processor

I have an AMD processor (and I will attach BIOS screenshots below) and I haven't used Android Studio for about a year or so, a bit less. Virtualization worked perfectly before but now it gives me an error saying "Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD, your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM). I have no clue why as SVM mode is on when I check BIOS. But here are some photos:

UPDATE: I managed to get it to the point where it now says "HAXM is required to run this AVD, HAXM not installed, I click install, allocate ram, it then goes on to stop installation and asks me to check the log which in turn says:

"This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) or it is being exclusively used by Hyper-V. HAXM cannot be installed.
Please ensure Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Features, or refer to the Intel HAXM documentation for more information."

So I go on and look in "turn windows features on and off" but there isn't any Hyper-V there, I remember seeing it there last year, but not anymore. Any ideas?

[image: CPU specs]

[image: second pic]

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Solution involved updating tools and then updating the app itself, then delete all the virtual devices, add a new one, download drivers it asked and it was good to go, no idea what exactly was wrong maybe out of date